# How to configure spring security cas client to retrieve custom attributes

Tags: spring-security, cas

I'm trying to setup a **CAS client with spring security**.
I started with [this article on the baeldung spring site](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cas-sso)  and [this sample code on github](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/cas/cas-secured-app)

**Everything work fine at this point.**

After, I tried  to Configure my client to **Obtain Proxy Granting Tickets** and custom attributes released by the server.

To do so I rely on the spring security documentation [spring security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cas-pt-client).

I walked into these steps into my **ticketValidator**

1. Add ProxyGrantingTicketStorage
2. Replace Cas20ServiceTicketValidator by Cas20ProxyTicketValidator (or Cas30ProxyTicketValidator to use V3 protocol)
3. Add ProxyCallbackUrl (http://localhost:9000/login/cas/proxyreceptor)

And in my **casAuthenticationFilter**:

1. Setup ProxyReceptorUrl (/login/cas/proxyreceptor)
2. Add ProxyGrantingTicketStorage

**The results of these settings :**

Without the ProxyCallbackUrl I get a answer from the cas server but without the tag proxyGrantingTicket. I think it's the reason why I don't retrieve the custom attributs in the principal. The ServiceTicketValidator doesn't treat the attributes if he doesn't find the ticket (method parseResponseFromServer of Cas20ServiceTicketValidator).

When I add ProxyCallbackUrl I get an error from the server:

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
  <cas:authenticationFailure code="INVALID_PROXY_CALLBACK">
     L'url de rappel du proxy  http://localhost:9000/login/cas/proxyreceptor
     n'a pu etre authentifiee.
  </cas:authenticationFailure>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

Could somebody help me to understand:

- why the cas server doesn't send the proxy Granting Ticket
- how to configure my client with a good Proxy Callback Url

Thank you

Comment: CAS server documentation about [validation response](https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/protocol/CAS-Protocol-Specification.html#252-response)

Comment: I think I don't have to configure my client to use a ProxyTicketValidator because my application is not a proxy but a final client of CAS. I am in the cas describe in [Web flow diagram](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html#web-flow-diagram) and not the [proxy-web-flow-diagram](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html#proxy-web-flow-diagram). Anyway i don't understand why CAS server don't send me the tag proxyGrantingTicket.

Comment: Hi, this is the default behavior because the proxy callback URL *needs* to be HTTPS.